How can a Python enum accept any value without raising ValueError
Suppose I am implementing a network service that receives commands. I want to have an enumeration of these commands, so I can write something like:
class Command(enum.Enum):
    ECHO = 0x01
    LOGIN = 0x02
    SEND_FILE = 0x03

def handle_packet(p: bytes):
    command = Command(p[0])
    if command == Command.ECHO:
        print(p[1:])
    elif ...
    elif ...
    else:
        print('Ignoring unknown command', command)

If the client supports a newer version of this protocol than my server, they might send a command that I don't have listed in my enum. For example, if the client sends me 0x04, the constructor Command(p[0]) will throw a ValueError.
Instead, I'd like command = Command(0x04) to create an instance where command.value = 4 and it has a name generated on-the-fly like COMMAND_04.

It would be a crude approach, but could you just add five or ten extra values with the generic names into your Enum? That could give you a fair amount of forward compatibility without much effort.

Don't do that. Just make a function that catches the exception and returns some sentinel value.

Isn't the point of an enum to enumerate all available values? If you receive an unavailable value, it shouldn't be an enum member, no? Instead, for this code, I would write a try-except that handles the ValueError.

Perhaps you should be using a dictionary instead of an Enum to begin with.

Don't fight against what an enumeration is supposed to be, just write a function to handle this logic and use the function.
class Command(enum.Enum):
    ECHO = 0x01
    LOGIN = 0x02
    SEND_FILE = 0x03


def byte_to_command(b: int) -> Command | int:
    try:
        return Command(b)
    except ValueError:
        return b


def handle_packet(p: bytes):
    command: Command | int = byte_to_command(p[0])
    if command == Command.ECHO:
        print(p[1:])
    elif ...
    elif ...
    else:
        print('Ignoring unknown command', command)


The above is quick and dirty, another approach would be to have a special member like UNKNOWN = -0x01 and return Command.UNKNOWN. But the approach above works in your specific case.

Not quite a direct answer to my original question, but there is an enum.IntEnum class which supports equality testing. With this, you can use ints instead of instantiating Command instances, but use the members for comparisons:
class Command(enum.IntEnum):
    ECHO = 0x01
    LOGIN = 0x02
    SEND_FILE = 0x03

def handle_packet(p: bytes):
    command: int = p[0]
    if command == Command.ECHO:
        print(p[1:])
    elif ...
    elif ...
    else:
        print('Ignoring unknown command', command)

The downside is you cannot access properties like command.value. The print() statement at the end will be less useful, because it only prints out the numeric value.

if you use enum.IntEnum, then you don't need to use int(command), because command is already an int. But again, this sort of defeats the point of using an enum to begin with. Why don't you just write a separate function?

Ok, I removed the reference to int(command). I don't know what you mean by "write a separate function"? To convert command numbers back to friendly names?

read my answer above
